# Azure Search throwing an error when an apostrophe is included

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

When performing an Azure search which includes an apostrophe - in this case, l'expedition - Azure throws an error,

```
  "Invalid expression: ')' or ',' expected at position 53 in '((search.ismatchscoring('navigation_title_s:(/.*\\\"l\\'expedition\\\".*/)',null, 'full', null))))'.\r\nParameter name: $filter"
```

This is the search that is being generated:

```
$filter=((search.ismatchscoring('navigation_title_s:(/.*\"l\'expedition\".*/)',null, 'full', null)))
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You can escape single quotes in OData by doubling them. In your case:

`$filter=((search.ismatchscoring('navigation_title_s:(/.*\"l''expedition\".*/)',null, 'full', null)))`

would work.

Comment: Thanks, that is ultimately the answer.  Unfortunately, this is being constructed somewhere within the bowels of Sitecore.  The regex is being escaped somewhere outside of the control of our code at this point...

Comment: @Giallo In that case, it's a bug in Sitecore. Please report it to them if you haven't already.